# Anonymous access pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I want to access my pentaho user console without login.Could it happen?How?

What i mean user console is page thats appear after login.Like url below:

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/home
```

I already follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Opening+Up+Some+Action+Sequences+for+Anonymous+Access) but i cant continue to the 3rd step.And the error said

> The requested resource () is not available.

Anyone have suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial may be slightly dated.  Here are the latest instructions from The Pentaho Security Guide:  http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsecurity_guide%2Ftask_removing_security.html

I have not enabled anonymous access myself, but have made other customizations to roles and the ACLs.  I reviewed these instructions and they seem reasonable and complete.

Good luck!

Comment: HI,

I already succedd bypass the login to PUC with anonymous.but i have problem here, in that tutorial the anonymous role has granted as administrator user. I want to make this anonymous role just as anonymous role.so if i'm not login, i just have limited access. Have an idea? Thx.

Comment: @guurnita:  Have you managed to preserve an optional login for yourself?  If so, you might try not doing or reversing step 9 from the instructions.  Obviously, take file backups here so that you do not inadvertently lock yourself out of the system.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option following the steps found in this guide: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0P0/150/040

The documentation might result confusing but it definitively works.

Basically the end result you should get is this:

- Autologin with AnonymousUser when you enter the pentaho URL
- AnonymousUser only has read privileges
- In case you want to edit you enter the login URL and use admin credentials